# Cannot resolve symbol @Url.Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Should be a simple problem but i dont know exactly why its like this.

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 website i have a simple view with a grid, and a cell action that calls a js function sending some parameters to this function.

```
function OnCellClick(param1, param2) {
        var urlAJAX = @Url.Action("GetJson", "PosicaoEstoque", new { p1 = param1 , p2 =param2}); }
```

So, like this i get the 'Cannot Resolve symbols' for the param1 and param2.
How can i solve it?

Comment: hi @ggui, I'm just curious, using the code from @Satpal's answer, can you actually get the value for `p2` in your `GetJson` method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use placeholder. Generate url using place holder parameters and then replace them with param

```
function OnCellClick(param1, param2) {
    var urlAJAX = '@Url.Action("GetJson", "PosicaoEstoque", new { p1 = -1 , p2 = -2})';
    urlAJAX = urlAJAX.replace('-1', param1).replace('-2', param2);
}
```

Comment: yes the function is called form client side and you are assigning the url from service side. So the variable param1 and param2  wont be available at javascript. So its better to have placeholder and replace them

Comment: hi @Satpal, good answer. But I'm wondering how OP can get the parameter `p2` in the action method.
Because it'll generate the URL like/PosicaoEstoque/GetJson?p1=aaa&amp;p2=bbb.

Comment: @Lin, As per understanding generated url will be `/PosicaoEstoque/GetJson?p1=aaa&p2=bbb`

Comment: @Satpal, thanks. But I got `&amp;` between the two parameters.

Comment: @Lin, that's weird as my answer doesn't impact how `Url.Action()` generates url

Comment: @Satpal, I know that's weird. but I got the interesting result.

Answer (score 1):

Without using `Url.Action` like below:

```
var urlAJAX = 'PosicaoEstoque/GetJson?p1=' + param1 + '&p2=' + param2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're mixing server-side and client-side code. You cannot simply put JavaScript variables in `Url.Action()`, as it runs on the server-side. What you can do is to put some dummy values as parameters and call JavaScript's `replace()` function on generated URL.

Check [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1723042.aspx?How+to+create+a+flipcart+like+panel+for+showing+products+in+gridview) for reference.